# Efficiently generate numpy array from list comprehension output?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a more efficient way than using `numpy.asarray()` to generate an array from output in the form of a `list`?

This appears to be copying everything in memory, which doesn't seem like it would be that efficient with very large arrays.

**(Updated) Example:**

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) # pretend this has thousands of elements
a2 = np.array([3,7,8])

results = np.asarray([np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)) for element in a2])
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to make much sense. Unless `element` is larger then all elements in `a1`, it is just the largest element of `a1`. In any case the approach will scale *very* badly for large `a1` for this kind of function, so what are you actually doing here? Also `np.frompyfunc` doesn't really speed up things. Note that the copying here should be very unimportant compared to the actual work done, trying to optimize things without knowing where your time is spend is usually a bad idea...

Comment: This was just for demonstration. What I'm trying to do is create arrays of values meeting some condition against a set of values in another array. Your point about optimization is a good one. I was just curious to find a *best practice* in this instance I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `np.fromiter`:

```
results = np.fromiter((np.amax(np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)) for element in a2), dtype=int, count=len(a2))
```

You don't need to specify `count` but it allows numpy to preallocate the array. Here are some timings I did on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/:

```
In [8]: %timeit np.asarray([np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)) for element in a2])                                 
1000 loops, best of 3: 161 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda element: np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)),1,1)(a2,out=np.empty_like(a2))   
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit np.fromiter((np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)) for element in a2),dtype=int, count=len(a2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.vectorize` won't work the way you want, because it doesn't respect an `out` parameter.  However, the lower-level `np.frompyfunc` will:

```
np.frompyfunc(lambda element: np.amax(np.where(a1 > element)),
              1, 1)(a2, out=np.empty_like(a2))
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of `frompyfunc`. This looks great. Thanks!